# COMMIT on top of the pt-query-digest output

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, percona, performance, percona-tools, slow-log

I've been optimizing my MySQL server and after tweaking a few queries, I ended up with the COMMIT item on top of the pt-query-digest output, as shown in the extract below:

```
# 322s user time, 770ms system time, 71.75M rss, 223.13M vsz
# Current date: Sat Oct  1 11:12:58 2016
# Hostname: XXXX
# Files: /home/tools/Slow10.log
# Overall: 1.08M total, 1.47k unique, 61.74 QPS, 0.17x concurrency _______
# Time range: 2016-10-01 06:15:09 to 11:06:35
# Attribute          total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============     ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Exec time          2913s     1us     14s     3ms    15ms    27ms   194us
# Lock time           123s       0      2s   113us   167us     3ms    42us
# Rows sent        1019.81k       0   8.58k    0.97    0.99   26.59       0
# Rows examine     314.86M       0   2.13M  305.82  234.30   7.13k       0
# Query size       321.03M       6  14.64k  311.81   1.14k  743.10   88.31

# Profile
# Rank Query ID           Response time   Calls  R/Call V/M   Item
# ==== ================== =============== ====== ====== ===== ============
#    1 0x813031B8BBC3B329 1676.7355 57.6%  70006 0.0240  0.02 COMMIT
#    2 0xBC10C51A724ECD57   61.8928  2.1%    211 0.2933  0.08 SELECT users
```

And the query is shown as:

```
# Query 1: 4.00 QPS, 0.10x concurrency, ID 0x813031B8BBC3B329 at byte 462955973
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
# Scores: V/M = 0.02
# Time range: 2016-10-01 06:15:09 to 11:06:34
# Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Count          6   70006
# Exec time     57   1677s     9us      2s    24ms    56ms    24ms    16ms
# Lock time      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Rows sent      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Rows examine   0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Query size     0 410.19k       6       6       6       6       0       6
# String:
# Databases    XXX_XX... (9419/13%)... 40 more
# Hosts        localhost
# Query_time distribution
#   1us  #
#  10us  #
# 100us  #
#   1ms  ####
#  10ms  ################################################################
# 100ms  #
#    1s  #
#  10s+
commit\G
```

Any word on how can I optimize this?

If further information is required please let me know!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 2016-02-10: The first analysis before any query optimization looked like:

```
# Rank Query ID Response time Calls R/Call V/M Item
# ==== ================== ================ ======= ====== ===== ==========
# 1 0x62057CDB69C17D23 18377.2125 46.3% 139328 0.1319 0.15 SELECT AAAA
# 2 0xEC77079791A0E274 6992.0443 17.6% 127446 0.0549 0.09 SELECT BBBB
# 3 0xB8A934DECC36D811 6283.1217 15.8% 247595 0.0254 0.03 UPDATE users_sessions
# 4 0x813031B8BBC3B329 2042.6094 5.1% 89046 0.0229 0.04 COMMIT
```

Server has 8Gb RAM with `innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G` with about 70 databases with 140 tables each.

EDIT 2016-10-06:

```
# grep innodb /etc/my.cnf
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
```

Comment: This is 'normal'.  Look down the list a short ways; you may find some slow query inside the transaction.

Comment: Hi Rick, as you can see in the rank the query #2 it only uses 2.1% of the time. Is there any way to pt-query-digest or log only Transactions? Thanks!

Comment: Well, let's check some other things.  How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Rick, server has 8Gb RAM, innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G

Comment: Please post the output of `grep innodb /etc/my.cnf`

Comment: Hi @RolandoMySQLDBA I just updated the main post, please view "EDIT 2016-10-06".

Answer (score 1):

Forensics...

- Median time for your `COMMITs`: 16ms.
- Typical time for spinning disk write: 10ms.
- Default setting of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`: 1, meaning flush to disk on every commit.

Conclusion:  The killer used the candlestick in the library. Or.. Most of what you are doing is very rapidly committing transactions.

Possible ways to speed up:

- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` -- This flushes once per second instead of once per transaction.  That is less 'safe', but for *some* users, the tradeoff is worth it.
- Batch you actions.  Instead of one `INSERT` per `COMMIT`, do lots of `INSERTs`.  The main cost in `COMMIT` is flushing one write to the rollback log, regardless of how much went on in the transaction.
- Hardware -- SSD - drops the 10ms to 1ms (or something like that); RAID with battery backed write cache - makes writes take virtually 0 ms, even without loss of safety.
- Since a few `COMMITs` are taking over 1 second, you could look for them and see if their transactions can be improved.

Comment: Rick, is there any way I can log all transactions excluding non transactions queries in order to identify how they are working and how to optimize them?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.  Suggest you stare at the source code.  Anyway, how much of a problem is `COMMIT` apparently causing?

Comment: "61.74 QPS, 0.17x concurrency" sounds like there is very little trouble.  And so little concurrency that one transaction is rarely hitting another.

Comment: Actually not that much, I've started with the following:

  
`# Rank Query ID           Response time    Calls   R/Call V/M   Item
# ==== ================== ================ ======= ====== ===== ==========
#    1 0x62057CDB69C17D23 18377.2125 46.3%  139328 0.1319  0.15 SELECT AAAA
#    2 0xEC77079791A0E274  6992.0443 17.6%  127446 0.0549  0.09 SELECT BBBB
#    3 0xB8A934DECC36D811  6283.1217 15.8%  247595 0.0254  0.03 UPDATE users_sessions
#    4 0x813031B8BBC3B329  2042.6094  5.1%   89046 0.0229  0.04 COMMIT`  
But  I was just wondering how could I further improve.

Answer (score 0):

## In short

Use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to get more information.

## Long version

This means your `COMMIT` taking lots of time.  There are serveral issues might cause it:

- CPU bound or I/O bound.

  In this case, you can find out which transaction is slow, and then you can optimize it.
- InnoDB locks.

  In this case, you can find out what kind of locks are acquired, and possible deadlocks (which might not be detected by InnoDB), and then optimize it.

Comment: Hi Gslin, what should I look for in the ´SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS´? Thanks!